# Dynamically create json using WCF service to feed MTDialog application

Tags: wcf, dialog, xamarin.ios, odata

I wish to create a MonoTouch MTDialog-based app that upon launching adds a single element to the MonoTouch Dialog and then render the screen.  This single element will be a JsonElement similar to this -

```
 var je = new JsonElement ("Dynamic Data", "http://tirania.org/tmp/demo.json");
```

as shown in the sample application.  However, instead of referencing a pre-built json file on a server, I wish to have the url point at a WCF OData service which will dynamically build the json data.

I am not sure what is the easiest way to do this.  I am a bit lost after reading over the documentation.  Is there some library I can include in my server-side C# app which I can then use to build out the elements and return as a json string of information?

I already have a WCF application up and running and just need to add an entry point which will call the method to create some simple json data for MonoTouch dialog to consume.

Any examples or suggestions are greatly appreciated as I am trying to get a simple solution completed by this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a C# JSON library?  How about JSON.NET http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

You might also look at ServiceStack.NET -- they have a MonoTouch client.